# Python, using more than 20 times mock.patch.object() and too many statically nested blocks error

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-3.6

I need to write the unit test code for a very fat method. And the method is calling the other methods many times, so I need to use mock for all the calling methods.
but when I using mock.patch.object more than 20 times, I got the error, too many statically nested blocks.

My code looks like this,

```
test_fat_method(self):
instance = FatClass()
with mock.patch.object(instance, '_method_1', return_value=1), \
...
with mock.patch.object(instance, '_method_22', return_value=1):
    result = instance.test_method()
    assert result
```

Is there any way I can avoid the error?

Comment: Instead use contex manager, why don't use mock as variables?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi May I ask for any sample code, please?

Answer (score 1):

I found context switches to work better when patching objects in other modules. To avoid the `SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks` error, one can do the following:

```py
import contextlib
from unittest import mock

# ...

mocks = (
    mock.patch.object(instance, '_method_1', return_value=1),
    # ...,
    mock.patch.object(instance, '_method_22', return_value=1),
)

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    patches = [stack.enter_context(m) for m in mocks]
    result = instance.test_method()
    assert result
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 alternatives to use `mock.patch` other than with context switch.

**As decorators**

As we're binding decorators in the method, we are appending items on `*args` from methods.

The bad part of this implementation, is handle with a list of mocks with no name.

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class Class:
    def func_1():
        return True
    def func_2():
        return True
    def func_3():
        return True

@patch.object(Class, 'func_1')
@patch.object(Class, 'func_2')
@patch.object(Class, 'func_3')
def test_class(*args):
    args[0].return_value = 3 # This is the last object patched.
    args[1].return_value = 2 # This is the second object patched.
    args[2].return_value = 1 # This is the first object patched.
    assert len(args) == 3    # Quantity of items in args (3 decorators.)
    assert Class().func_1() == 1
    assert Class().func_2() == 2
    assert Class().func_3() == 3
```

If you have any doubts about the order of decorators take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together/1594484#1594484)

**As obejcts**

This solution is more verbose, but easier to maintain. However, I would choice this approach.

```
def test_class_alternative():
    mock_func_1 = patch('Class.func_1', return_value=1)
    mock_func_2 = patch('Class.func_2', return_value=2)
    mock_func_3 = patch('Class.func_3', return_value=3)

    assert Class().func_1() == 1
    assert Class().func_2() == 2
    assert Class().func_3() == 3
```